# How to create packedbubble with HighchartsReact

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to use something like [that](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vro2wzL4/) : 
If you can give me working example with react and packedbubble it will be very helpful.
the issue that I am using react and trying to do something like:

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {
        options: {
          title: {
            text: 'My chart'
          },
          series: [{
            data: [1, 2, 3]
          }]
        }

      }
      }


        render() {
    return (
   <HighchartsReact highcharts = {Highcharts} options={this.state.options}/>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create packedbubble you have to load `highcharts-more` module:

```
require("highcharts/highcharts-more")(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-8pkxr